# Move toward transform.forward, ignoring rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is attached to a camera:

```
transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * transform.forward * mod;
transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right * mod;
```

I've used .forward and .right because the player is able to rotate the camera on the Y axiz, thus no matter which way the camera is facing the forward key will always move the camera relatively forward, the left key will move it relatively left and so on. Just to clarify - I want it to move in local space, not world space so forward is the direction it's facing, not necessarily Vector3(0,0,1).

The camera is free roaming and has no parent or target to follow.

The problem is the camera has an X rotation of 45 to look down. Using transform.forward will thus modify it's height. There is also some scroll code to change the cameras height so I don't want to set the hight to a fixed value. How can I limit the movement to X and Z only, preferably without parenting it it an empty?

Update: this code works but it's not pretty, I'm sure there is a more elegant solution using Vector3.Project, as xyLe_ is suggesting. If I figure it out I'll add to his answer.

```
mod = Time.deltaTime * 30;
float yPos = transform.position.y;
pos = transform.position;
pos += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * transform.forward * mod;
pos.y = yPos;
pos += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right * mod;
pos += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * transform.up * mod * -30;
```

Comment: [Math.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) could help.

Comment: So you want to use "world" forward direction? If that's your case then world directions are constant `Vector3.Up = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);`

Comment: rotate `transform.forward` by your rotation around `transform.right` to align it with the x-z-plane

Comment: @ m.rogalski Thanks, but the player can rotate the camera so I don't want to use world space, it needs to be local

Comment: @ xyLe_ - that sounds like the sort of thing I'm after, can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Whyat do you mean by "45 to look down"?

Comment: @ Programmer It's default rotation is (45, 0, 0) and it's height is 40 so it looks down on the playing field. Y rotation can change, the others should not.

Comment: Ok. Will the X ever change?

Comment: X rotation? No. X pos yes.

Comment: Did you solve this? I

Comment: Yes, but not in any classy way, I'll post what I've done. xyLe_ gave me the idea to record the original Y position but I could get the suggested Vec3.Project approach to work, can't quite get my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might talk nonsense right now, but it seems pretty simple to me:

`Vector3 desiredDirection = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, transform.position.y, transform.forward.z))`

Just project `transform.forward` onto the x-z plane that is settled at the height of `transform.position.y`. Doing this (usually) results in a slightly shorter vector, so you have to renormalize it.

To visualize:

[image: vec img]

If I understand you correctly, `transform.forward` corresponds to the black vector and you want to have the green vector. By setting the y component of the black vector to the y component of the red dots positions y component, you get the purple vector, which has to be renormalized.

Comment: That's in in a nutshell, yes. I'll see if I can code it, I may have to come back for your help though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has been solved, the solution below should help other people having this problem.

Here is is a proper way to move toward `transform.forward` while ignoring its rotation:

**1**.Get the `transform.forward`.

**2**.Convert it to Local Space with `InverseTransformDirection`

**3**.Set the `y` axis to `0`;

**4**.Normalize it with `dir.Normalize()`;

**5**.Append the new pos to `transform.position`.

```
public float mod = 2;

void Update()
{
    //Get Forward face
    Vector3 dir = transform.forward;
    //Convert to local Space
    dir = transform.InverseTransformDirection(dir);
    //Reset/Ignore y axis
    dir.y = 0;
    dir.Normalize();

    //Append the new pos to the `transform.position`.
    transform.position += dir * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * mod;
    transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right * mod;
}
```

**Another Method(Not Recommended):**

Since the camera is tilted to 45 angle:

**1**.Rotate it to `-45`

**2**.Move the camera normally

**3**.Rotate it back to `45`

```
public float startingOffset = 45;
public float mod = 2;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Rotate it to -45
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-startingOffset, 0, 0));

    // Move the camera normally
    transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * transform.forward * mod;
    transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right * mod;

    //Rotate it back to 45
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(startingOffset, 0, 0));
}
```

Both these should work but the preferred way should be the first one.